# Performing local JMX connection via VisualVM

Tags: java, jvm, jmx, visualvm, mbeans

I have a Wildfly 26 server that I am running with the following VM args:

```bash
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logback.xml  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1990
```

My `standalone.xml` has the properties:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
    <expose-resolved-model/>
    <expose-expression-model/>
    <audit-log/>
    <sensitivity/>
    <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
</subsystem>
.
.
.
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
.
.
.
   <socket-binding name="jmx-connector" port="1990"/>
.
.
.
</socket-binding-group>
```

The server comes up fine, but I can't seem to connect to it via VisualVM. [This guide](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/jmx_ref_guide/html_single/index.html#d0e183) seems to suggest adding `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi` in the JMX URL field (`1990` instead of `9999` in my case), but this seems to not be working. In the screenshot below you can see all of the connections that I have tried, with several different ports. All of them are grayed-out on the menu on the left, with the connection unable to be made. You can see that I have tried several connection URLs, none of which have worked.

[image: All URLs I have attempted for VisualVM]

What should I be adding to the `Connection` field?

[image]

Is there perhaps a misconfiguration in the XML? Or in the VM args?